# User time limits

Tags: settings, system

Is there any way to set time limits on a user?  We have children and want to limit the time they spend on it.  The user admin section is a bit slim on that.

Comment: Take a look at the script I wrote for another but similar question on askubuntu site: http://askubuntu.com/a/623260/295286 . If you'd be interested in something like that, I can modify the script to suit your needs and post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

#### elementary OS

Currently, elementary doesn't provide parental controls. However, it's something that's [on their radar](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-plugs/+bug/1326088).

---

#### Timekpr App

You could try [timekpr](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/timekpr-restrict-computer-access-ubuntu)

It should fit your intention. It would be nice to tell us, if this worked as
expected.